# GAE Datastore Viewer by GQL WHERE query for a String does not seem to work

Tags: google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery

Here is my data:

ID/Name  createdTime     customerName    itemName    price   quantity    status  user_orderid
id=5681726336532480  2013-10-12 05:07:47.794000  "joe"   "Nexus 5"   349.00  1   "pending"   "1"

Running either of these two queries gives me data:
SELECT * FROM order
SELECT * FROM order ORDER BY createdTime DESC

But running the following gives me nothing:
SELECT * FROM order WHERE status = 'pending'
SELECT * FROM order WHERE status = 'pending' ORDER BY createdTime DESC

I see results when doing the following:
SELECT * FROM order WHERE status != 'pending'

So I know that the WHERE clause is having some effect. I just can't get 'pending' in the GQL query to match "pending" in the datastore.

My index is defined as so:
order status ▲ , createdTime ▼   Serving

I deleted the record and re-adding it to make sure that it was created after the index was in place. That did not help.
I read the GQL Reference page over and over but didn't find anything really helpful. Some posts on stackoverflow indicated that my syntax for doing a WHERE = 'string' is correct.
But no matter what I do, I can't get this to return data either for the Datastore Viewer or my actual application which is trying to run this query.

I ran into this while doing the App Engine code lab Exercise 8 hosted here: http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/codelabexercise8.html

**Update:** Here is the model as requested:

```
/**
 * <p>Java class for order complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="order">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="customer" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *         &lt;element name="status" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *         &lt;element name="user_orderid" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *         &lt;element name="item" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *         &lt;element name="quantity" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}positiveInteger"/>
 *         &lt;element name="price" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}decimal"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *       &lt;attribute name="id" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}long" />
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "order", propOrder = {
    "customer",
    "status",
    "userOrderid",
    "item",
    "quantity",
    "price"
})
public class Order {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String customer;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String status;
    @XmlElement(name = "user_orderid", required = true)
    protected String userOrderid;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String item;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected BigInteger quantity;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected BigDecimal price;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected Long id;

    ... getters and setters ...
```

Here is the database index:

```
<datastore-indexes>
    <datastore-index kind="order" ancestor="false" source="auto">
        <property name="status" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="createdTime" direction="desc"/>
    </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

**Update:** Fixed. The data should look like this instead of what I posted above.
ID/Name  createdTime     customerName    itemName    price   quantity    status  user_orderid
id=5760616295825408  2013-10-12 19:25:13.098000  joe     Nexus 5     349.00  1   pending     12

Comment: If your syntax were wrong, you'd probably be getting some error messages. Are you getting any? How did you create the record? Could you show us your model/data structure?

Comment: There is no error, just an empty result set when it appears that results should be returned.

Comment: "No results in Empty namespace." is what the Datastore Viewer returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have quote marks around several of the fields in your data, so it won't match your query.  Clean up the data and you should be good to go.

Comment: Doh! Yeah the XML file that I created by reverse engineering the .XSD file has ""s on the string element values. Removing those resolved the query issues! I also tried doing the query with WHERE status = '"pending"' and that worked, so it proved that the quotes in the data were causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may set the `status` as `indexed=False` or `TextProperty` (which imply unindexed).
Please post the model definition here so we have more details to answer your questions!

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that 'status' is an undocumented reserved word?

That would explain this behaviour.